# How do I remove the session cookie in ASP.NET 2010?

Tags: asp.net-membership

I have an ASP.NET 2010 web app that uses the default membership controls. When I log in, the Login control on the Master reveals a Log out control. When I click that, it does redirect me to Default page, but I notice that if I naviagte back to an authenticated page, it lets me in. So I added the following code when the log out link is clicked to ensure the cookie is killed,

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
Session.Abandon()
```

But I can still navigate to the authenticated page. It only stops me if I actually close the browser and reopen it.

Here is my web.config....

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms 
        name=".ASPXAUTH"
        loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx"
        protection="All"
        timeout="2880"
        slidingExpiration="true"
        defaultUrl="~/Authenticated/User/UserHome.aspx"
        />
        </authentication>

    <membership>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
              passwordFormat="Hashed"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
             connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
             enablePasswordReset="true" 
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
             requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
             minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
             passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
             applicationName="/"/>
            </providers>
        </membership>

        <profile>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
            </providers>
        </profile>

        <roleManager enabled="true">
   <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"
     name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
    <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
     type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
   </providers>
  </roleManager>
```

Comment: Can you show us your web.config?

Comment: Post your Authorization section. If you don't have one, that explains this behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
Session.Abandon()

// Now, forward to a safe unauthenticated page if SignOut() doesn't already do this.
Response.Redirect("/default.aspx")
```

This attempts to set the ASP.NET_SessionID cookie to expire immediately. The browser should remove it from its collection. I've not run this up in VS2010, so please take my typing with a grain of salt.

Let me know if this works for you.